# Help with understanding inferential concept

Tags: density-function, value-of-information

I am reading an old article on Information Value Theory and to properly understand the material, I need to get my head around the following inferential concept where ***u***, ***v*** are random variables and ***S*** is the state of information.

> A most important inferential concept is expansion; it allows us to encode our knowledge in a problem in the most convenient form. The concept of expansion permits us to introduce a new consideration into the problem. Suppose, for example, that we must assign a probability distribution to a random variable *u*. We may find it easier to assign a probability distribution to *u* if we had previously specified the value of another random variable *v* and we may also find it easy to assign a probability distribution directly to *v*. In this case the expansion equation,
>
> {*u|S*} = ∫<sub>*v*</sub> {*u|vS*} {*v|S*}
>
> shows that all we have to do to find {*u|S*} is multiply {*u|vS*} by {*v|S*} and sum over all possible values of the random variable *v*.

I will be grateful if someone could explain what {*u|vS*} means. I am no good statistician and will appreciate an intuitive explanation on a concrete example.

Comment: If $u$ is continuous, $\{u|v,S\}$ means the conditional density of $u$ given the values of $v$ and $S$. (Usually, as I have done you'd put a comma between them though.)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a reformulation of Bayes rule. That is, the probability of an event $u$ given $S$ can be expressed as 
$$
P(u\mid S)=\int_v P(u \mid v \cap S)P(v\mid S)
$$
where $u,v,S$ are events of random variables.

Answer (score 0):

example. you need to forecast whether you make it or break it next winter with your flower shop. you know that in cold winters it's 50%/50%, and in warm winters it's 80% to make it. next you look at the whether data. and it turns out that 60% of time the winters are cold, and 40% they're warm.

your information set S is the whether data and your prior winter success history. $\{v|S\}$ is the probabilities of cold/warm winters. $\{u|vS\}$ is your probability to make it conditional on whether. so your forecast is 50%*60%+80%*40%=62% to make it next winter